# Scaling dimension in Kerr/CFT

Tags: black-holes, scattering, scaling

Let's consider the scattering of a scalar field around a Kerr-AdS Black Hole. In terms of the Kerr/CFT correspondence how can I get the relation between the scaling dimension and the mass of the field ( I suppose that they could be related as in the AdS/CFT conjecture, where you study the field near the boundary expanding it like $\phi \sim z^{\Delta}$)